# Rails - No proper access to self join model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have model called Section, and I want section to be able to have many Sections - so a Self Joins seems like a place to start.

I setup my code like this:

**Model file**

```
class Section < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :offer
    has_many :offer_items

    # Self joins:
    has_many :child_sections, class_name: "Section", foreign_key: "parent_id"
    belongs_to :parent_section, class_name: "Section", optional: true
end
```

**Migration file**

```
class CreateSections < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :sections do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.references :offer, foreign_key: true

      t.references :parent_section, foreign_key: true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

As you can see I set `belongs_to :parent_section` as optional, as no every section should has its parent.

When I print `attribute_names` of my Section model it says:

```
=> ["id", "name", "offer_id", "parent_section_id", "created_at", "updated_at"]
```

Trying to retrieve child_sections gets me an error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: sections.parent_id: SELECT "sections".* FROM "sections" WHERE "sections"."parent_id" = ?
```

Where did I make my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have `parent_id` in your `sections`

change this:

```
 has_many :child_sections, class_name: 'Section', foreign_key: 'parent_id'
```

on this:

```
 has_many :child_sections, class_name: 'Section', foreign_key: 'parent_section_id'
```

Comment: All the little stuff. Last time I forgot a letter "s" and this time... Thanks! Dzięki!

Comment: The one thing that does not work is if I want to create a child section it does not get saved, and this is because of offer_id is nil). Setting offer_id while creating a subsection manually solves that problem. Is there a way to actually do it automatically?

Comment: You can create something callback in `Section` like `before_create` , also i'm not sure but i think you can get all sections from offer in this way:
`something_offer.sections.joins(:child_sections)`.

Comment: That is perfect. I've already implemented the before_create that works the way I want it to. Thanks again.